# a date or the date

Tags: grammaticality, articles

I was thinking of a sentence;

> July 16, 1999, is the date at which my dog died.

It shows the specific date at which my dog died.

But when I use "a" instead of "the", I think I am focusing more on the type of the date.

> July 16, 1999, is a date at which my dog died.

As is the case with the day:

> That was a day my dog died (type, or kind of the day)
>
> That was the day my dog died (identifying the day; the specific day)

Am I correct about the articles involving the date?

Comment: I really won't use 'a' for this, I mean, when there's an exact date... It sounds pretty awkward. Well, maybe it's just me. (others might have a different opinion regarding this) Unless that specific date is being identified as a part of something else? i.e., "July 16, 1999 is a date in 1999." (obviously... something to that effect?)

Comment: In the case of "That was a day my dog died (type, or kind of the day)", could you suppose an actual example and add it to your question? I think it is possible to have *a date* in it, but it would have to refer to something other than a specific date.

Comment: @user3169 Yes. "He bought the house with a big backyard. This combination tells the listener which specific house he bought."
"He bought a house with a big backyard. This combination tells the listener what kind of house he bought, but not the specific house he bought." http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm

Comment: But by using "a date" you are trying to say the dog died on an unspecified day, which is not possible since you specified *the* date.

Comment: @user3169 What if I just use "that was" instead of a specific date like July 6 1980?

Comment: The pronoun *that* still refers to the date, since the dog can only die on one day, not two. Also, if you check definitions, [*date*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=date) almost always refers to a specific day. In some contexts (not this one), "a day" could be possible.

Comment: @user3169 But what I don't understand is, there is only one house he bought, as there is only one day that the dog died on. So why is "a" house and "the" house is possible, while the day is not?

Comment: @whitedevil - This is just standard meanings for *a* or *the*.  *A* thing just means a random, nonspecific example of things.  *The* thing means a specific thing.  As there was only one day on which your dog died, it's a specific thing.  In the example "he bought a house", yes, there is only one house that he bought, but in that sentence, what matters grammatically is that it's just a random nonspecific house.  In an example like "the house with the red door", then it's not just any house, but one specific house, just like the day your dog died is one specific day.

Comment: "He bought a house with a big backyard." doesn't explicitly tell you which house he bought. There could be 5 houses in that area with big backyards.

Comment: @user3169 Yes,I agree with that. But it does not always mean that there is more than one substance which the indefinite article is modifying, right? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93980/difference-between-the-and-a-in-this-context-with-relative-clause Here is a similar question from which I became curious. The answerer stated that, in case of "a book I told you about", If you say "this is a book I told you about yesterday," _it might suggest that it was one of several books, or **it might mean that you don't think I remember it**._  I am so frustrated and tired, not knowing why....

Comment: ..."day" cannot be used in the same way. If I say "this is a book I told you about", it certainly suggests that there is only one book that I told this "you" about. I thought that if I say "_this is a day my dog died_", it implies that the idea is introduced for the first time and you didn't know about it, and it is emphasizing the type of the day. Can you please explain why it doesn't work that way?

Comment: @stangdon Please see my comments above. I still am very confused :)

Comment: @whitedevil - Yes, you can say "this is **a** book that I told you about", but that means it is one of several books you told me about.  If you said "this is **the** book that I told you about", it would mean that you told me about only one book.  It's true that in "this is __ day that my dog died", you're introducing it for the first time, but you're also emphasizing its uniqueness: not just any day, but the day **that my dog died**.  That's why we have to use **the**.  I understand that this is confusing!  This is one of those times when English is really specific and yet hard to explain.

Comment: Anyway, this discussion is getting very lengthy, so we should probably move it to chat.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you! So do you mean that I cannot say that "this is a book that I told you about" if there is only one book I told you about? So it does not imply that I don't think you remember it? There should be more than one book to justify the use of indefinite article with "a book"?

Comment: @stangdon And I don't know how to move it to chat, but I think it is a good idea if we do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your dog is capable of dying more than once, it does not make sense to say

> July 16, 1999 is a date on which my dog died.

A better example of using **a** for a date would be

> July 16, 1999 is an important date for me because my dog died on that day.

You could have many dates that are important to you, but there can only be one day on which your dog died, so it must be

> July 16, 1999 is the date on which my dog died.

A couple of comments: *date **on** which* is much more widely used than *date **at** which. It would be much more idiomatic to use **the day that**, for example:

> July 16, 1999 is the day that my dog died.

Comment: Or simply, _July 16, 1999 is the day my dog died_. We don't even need the "that". In many contexts, _My dog died on July 16, 1999_ might be even better.

Comment: "He bought the house with a big backyard. This combination tells the listener which specific house he bought." "He bought a house with a big backyard. This combination tells the listener what kind of house he bought, but not the specific house he bought." http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm So doesn't "a" day and "the" day work the same way? I mean, there is only one house he bought, as there is only one day that the dog died on.

Comment: @whitedevil: You can use **a** for a kind of day, but you have to choose a kind that there can be more than one of:  **a weekday**, **a thursday**,  **a rainy day**,  **a busy day**, **a fourth of july**, but not **a fourth of july 1999**. There is only one house that he bought, but there are many with a big backyard.

Comment: Thank you! So "a" can be used only when there is more than one substance that "a" is modifying? But it does not always mean that there is more than one substance which the indefinite article is modifying, right? ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93980/… Here is a similar question from which I became curious. The answerer stated that, in case of "a book I told you about", If you say "this is a book I told you about yesterday," _it might suggest that it was one of several books, or **it might mean that you don't think I remember it**_. So can there be just one and only one substance and "a" is....

Comment: ....still used?

Comment: @whitedevil: in my opinion, "this is a book I told you about" can only be sensibly used when the book is one of several that I told you about. Whether I think you remember or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct about how you used "the" to identify the specific day your dog died.

> That was a day my dog died

To me, on first hearing this sentence, it doesn't sound like you had more than one dog and one of them died on that day. The sentence implies there was one dog, and it died on more than one day. Of course this doesn't make sense and listeners may realise you mean you had more than one dog, but they might not. Either way the sentence will be confusing. However, this is easily fixed by implying you had more than one dog:

> That was a day one of my dogs died.

Comment: "He bought the house with a big backyard. This combination tells the listener which specific house he bought." "He bought a house with a big backyard. This combination tells the listener what kind of house he bought, but not the specific house he bought." englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm So doesn't "a" day and "the" day work the same way? I mean, there is only one house he bought, as there is only one day that the dog died on.